# jQuery ui selectmenu vertical position offset (relatively to buttons in this line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, positioning, jquery-ui-selectmenu

In my form I place control elements in a line: button, select box, checkbox. It looks logically right. But since I've started using jQuery UI I see strange vertical of select box.
Here's the example from jquery-ui site, a little bit shortened: https://jsfiddle.net/Tertium/z829pay7

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu( { width: 200});
    $( "#files" ).selectmenu({ width: 200});
    $( "#but1" ).button();
    $( "#but2" ).button();

    });
```

Tested on jquery 1.11.2 and 1.10.2, jquery-ui: 1.11.3, all settings/css by default.
How I can show them in line or at least valigned by middle? Tried panning, margin, div, table - no effect at all.

And screenshot just in case:

[image: before and after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align : middle;`on your select-menu and button to align them vertically :

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z829pay7/4/)

Comment: wow, great! even  .ui-selectmenu-button { vertical-align : middle; } was enough. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I've just noticed that .ui-button are already aligned vertically in jquery-ui.css. Let's update this jsfiddle.