# align jqueryui's button and selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have created a select menu next to a button. I wonder how can I get the select menu be at the same Y of the button? (Ideally I would like it to be of the same height too but that is another thing I guess...)

As the shown code I have no configuration other than the select width:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button>button</button>
    <select>
        <option>nacho</option>
        <option>tama</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jqueryui JS

```
$('button').button();
$('select').selectmenu({
    width: 120 // Needed to show see options
});
```

Current Result:

[image]

Fiddle that show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/9xv7jqn4/2/

Is this a bug or a setting I am missing? Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the answers, I am still testing them in my code... I am also interested in know why this happens? Why the selectemenu is taking more space than it looks? Is this a bug of selectmenu widget?

Comment: I found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784761/jquery-ui-selectmenu-vertical-position-offset-relatively-to-buttons-in-this-lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on thread: "[jQuery ui selectmenu vertical position offset (relatively to buttons in this line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784761/jquery-ui-selectmenu-vertical-position-offset-relatively-to-buttons-in-this-lin) " and suggestions here too I ended up adding a couple of rules that fix my case.

I don't know why but ui-selectmenu-button is not vertical-aligned as other buttons. Also decreased the padding of inner text so it looks almost (not exactly) the same height as other buttons.

```
.ui-selectmenu-button {
    vertical-align: middle;
}                                                                                                                                                                  
.ui-selectmenu-button .ui-selectmenu-text {
    padding-top: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this css:

```
display: inline-flex;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Your fiddle with the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/9xv7jqn4/3/

Comment: inline-flex is not supported in IE up to IE10 http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-flex

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
vertical-align: top;
```

for your button like here: https://jsfiddle.net/9xv7jqn4/4/

```js
$('button').button();
$('select').selectmenu({width: 120});
```

```css
div,
button,
select{
    border: thin dotted red;
    
}
span {
    border: thin dotted blue;
}
.one{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class='one'>button</button>
    <select>
        <option>nacho</option>
        <option>tama</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is to add wrappers like here: https://jsfiddle.net/9xv7jqn4/6/

```js
$('button').button();
$('select').selectmenu({width: 120});
```

```css
div,
button,
select{
    border: thin dotted red;
    
}
span {
    border: thin dotted blue;
}
.w{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class='w'>
    <button>button</button>
    </div>
    <div class='w'>
    <select>
        <option>nacho</option>
        <option>tama</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```